# Offline tiles while slow internet in MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mbtiles

I have an `MKMapView` and I am providing the tiles for it. Now my user can download offline tiles onto their devices. But they of course only do so for selected parts. So some parts I have offline tiles, some parts I don't.

Now if the user doesn't have an internet connection it's no problem. All requests for online tiles will fail right away and the MapView will continue asking for other tiles. Perfect!

BUT... Now my user has super bad internet. So not no internet, but bad internet. Super slow Internet!
Now my MapView will be asking for surrounding tiles while the user zooms into his location of interest. My MapView is asking for those surrounding tiles, but until those Network-Requests fail, it will not continue asking for more tiles (tiles that I would have offline and could provide right away).

So... For my user it seems as if the offline tiles are not working... He would have to wait quite a bit until all requests time out and the MapView would be focusing on newer tiles.

How can I fix this problem?????